# mod_rewrite - Send everything that doesn't exist to index.php

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I would like to have my .htaccess file rewrite anything that doesn't exist to the index.php file. So for example: `www.example.com/category/subcategory/product1/` would be rewritten to `index.php?request=category/subcategory/product1`

I want to perform a check to see if the directory exists first though, and if it does, do not rewrite. I have something like this at the moment, but just need to know how I can get the requested URL into the PHP `$_GET` variable:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php [L]
```

Advanced thanks for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are almost there:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?request=$1 [L,QSA]
```

TBH, there is no real need to put requested URL into `$_GET` variable -- you can ALWAYS access original (requested) URL via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` -- the only difference is that `REQUEST_URI` will always start with leading slash (e.g. `/category/subcategory/product1`).